# How to build a door shared by two jamb openings

Tags: doors

To save space in a small apartment, I want to build a door into the bathroom that when closed, will (obviously) shut off the full bathroom, but when the door is open (opens inwards) will close off the toilet area. I have seen this in a hotel in the UK before.

How can I build a door like this?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a pocket door? A photo or drawing would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like a door that is shared between two perpendicular doorways.

Comment: It's an intriguing idea, but "any thoughts" questions are off-topic at SE. We're not a discussion forum, so questions need to be more specific in nature.

Comment: Does this door actually close and latch in both doorways?  Or just sit in front of the second doorway?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done fairly easily, with normal hinges too. It would take a bit of alternative framing and jamb work.

Open any normal "in swinging" door 90° and look at the gap between the door and jamb on the hinge side. This is what you have to hide. If you look at the pictures you will see that the door on the right is hung in a normal fashion with traditional jamb configuration. The other door has framing and jamb work that is "built out" away from the wall; the hinges end up buried on that side and the gap is eliminated.

One challenge is that a normal lockset will not work (note in picture there is no lockset installed). You would need an alternative style of catch that works in both directions, such as a large bullet catch (see below), and some method of ensuring privacy (like a flush bolt, surface bolt, or old-school hook & eye).

[image]

You may be restricted on the types of privacy device you use (especially for rentals or public bulding) as normally a method of emergency "unlatching" is required, in case someone inside has a medical emergency or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

On this kind of unusual design, I would strongly recommend experimenting with some models. I can see several problems related to how the hinge pin is located relative to the doorways which would make standard for frame construction impossible for one of the other doorway, and unless you use an unusual hinge... I think the best way to solve it is going to be to model one doorway with the door, swing the door into the 90-degree position, build a frame aroungpd it there, and then figure out how to construct those shapes in proper framing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old BUT I also want to do this (One Door two Jambs), and I also had seen it at a Hotel in the UK. Holiday Inn Express in Edinburgh (Cowgate). John, the Maintenance manager, kindly took the time to answer the weird question from Australia. "Thanks Mate"

https://www.imperiallocks.co.uk/products/bathroom-mortice-locks/G8072/

A bit of mucking around to get the Hinges and Jambs right but the latch was the hard bit to identify.(mines actually a 3 position door):)